# Discrete log over a prime

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, cryptography

I have a prime $p$ such that $p-1=2 p_1p_2$ such that $p_1$ has $200$ digits in base $2$ and $p_2$ has 50. I want to find discrete logarithm of $a^b =c \pmod p$. That is I want to find $b$ given $a,c, p$.
I know the remainder of $b \pmod{p_1}$. How can I use this information to find $b$? Of course I can check all  possible options in $[0, p_2-1]$ and use Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT) to find $b$.
But can we do better than this?

Comment: $p_1$ and $p_2$ are integers, I suppose they can be composite. I understand the question like this : $p_1$ and $p_2$ are $2$ integers ($200$ digits and $50$ digits) ; $p_1 \times p_2+1$ is a prime.  etc.

Comment: Are $p_1$ and $p_2$ primes or could they be composite?

Answer (score 1):

There are various algorithms for finding discrete logarithms. For the bit sizes you specify, this is certainly possible to do quite efficiently, for example a few of the algorithms you can use to accomplish this are [Pohlig–Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm), [Baby-step giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step), [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm).

As you may know, finding discrete logarithms efficiently is known as the "Discrete logarithm problem", which is of significant interest in the field of Cryptography, owing to the fact that a lot of the common public encryption schemes in wide use today are based on the hardness of computing discrete logarithms (over prime integer fields with a $p$ that has a lot more bits than what you have here, or [over elliptic curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_cryptography) which are a different beast).

If you want to see a bit more of "state of the art" results regarding this subject, [this may be of interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm_records).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how can I use the knowledge of b \mod p_1 to find b in Pollard rho? Pollard rho time complexity is square root. Can we find 2^25 in this case?

Comment: @Sanu - You may be able to improve the algorithm if you can reduce the search space via the additional information. I don't know what you mean by the question "Can we find $2^{25}$"